# Access webhook URL from browser

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-webhooks

I have created a runbook in Azure automation and have enabled a webhook for it, I am able to invoke the webhook using powershell
Is there any other option to invoke the webhook in the browser not going with powershell or with any other code

$webhookURI= "xxxx"
Invoke-WebRequest -Method Post -Uri $webhookURI

Answer (score 0):

You can install **Postman** on your machine to make any kind of HTTP request. **This is the recommended and simplest way to invoke your Azure Webhooks (or any HTTP API calls or hooks), when you don't want to write any PowerShell scripts or code.**
https://www.postman.com/downloads/

Alternatively you can even use **Postman directly in your browser** if you prefer not to install any software. You will need to sign up first : https://web.postman.co/

Postman provides you with a nice clean and easy to use UI to create and send requests to API endpoints and view responses. Once you create a set of requests, you can even use the collection runner to run all saved requests with a click of a button and write Postman tests for your responses to validate if the requests are successful.

You can see how to create and send HTTP requests using Postman here : https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/requests/

[image]

Postman also has a command line runner called **Newman** which can be used to run your saved postman requests using the terminal or windows cmd/powershell and integrates nicely with devops pipelines if required (for integration testing in CICD) [https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/#:~:text=Newman%20is%20a%20command%2Dline,directly%20from%20the%20command%20line.&text=Newman%20maintains%20feature%20parity%20with,the%20collection%20runner%20in%20Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/using-newman-cli/command-line-integration-with-newman/#:%7E:text=Newman%20is%20a%20command%2Dline,directly%20from%20the%20command%20line.&text=Newman%20maintains%20feature%20parity%20with,the%20collection%20runner%20in%20Postman).